# No logs generated: Skywalking OAP and Webapp won't start on Windows 10 with JDK-17

Tags: skywalking

I have downloaded the latest verion of Skywalking APM( vrsion 9.4) in my windows 10. And I also install jdk-17. Now whenever I am running the 'startup.bat' file from Skywalking directory it pops up two command prompt and get closed immediately. No logs file are generated and Skywalking OAP and Webapp doesn't start. And also there is no error in command prompt.

I have followed this reference for Skywalking https://bestcodepaper.com/microservice-link-tracking-component-skywalking/but still the same problem.
Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?
Thank you in advance!